# Пытаюсь решить из задачника и не могу понять одного момента

Tags: php

Задача следующая:

*Вывести на экран все счастливые билеты. Счастливый билет - это когда сумма первых трех цифр в номере билета равна сумме второй тройки цифр (номер шестизначный). Подсчитайте сколько счастливых билетов существует и какой % они составляют от общего числа билетов.
Пример: 123015 - счастливый.*

Решил попробовать через массив:

```
function pre($arr){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
}   

$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    if($i < 10){
        $arr[] = '00000' . $i;
    }
    elseif($i < 100){
        $arr[] = '0000' . $i;
    }
    elseif($i < 1000){
        $arr[] = '000' . $i;
    }
    elseif($i < 10000){
        $arr[] = '00' . $i;
    }
    elseif($i < 100000){
        $arr[] = '0' . $i;
    }
    else{
        $arr[] = $i;
    }
}

$lucky = array();
foreach($arr as $str){
    if($str[0] + $str[1] + $str[2] == $str[3] + $str[4] + $str[5]){
        $lucky[] = $str;
    }
}
echo count($lucky);
pre($lucky);
```

С 000000 до билета #099990 все правильно выводится. А потом выводятся #100000, 100001, 100002 и т.д, не обращая внимания на условия... Почему сначала условие соблюдается (и выводятся 4839 элементов массива), но как только перебор номеров билета переходит 099990, все рушится?

В итоге решил иначе:

```
$lucky = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){
    $str = substr('00000' . $i, -6);
    if($str[0] + $str[1] + $str[2] == $str[3] + $str[4] + $str[5]){
        $lucky[] = $str;
    }
}
pre($lucky);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ очевиден:) Присмотритесь к своему коду. Вы заметили что со строкой можно работать как с массивом то есть $s[2], но с числом так делать нельзя.

Дальше в момент конкатенации вы неявно приводите счетчик к типу строка и работаете с ним как и хотели. Но в последний момент у вас число и вы получаете ошибки.

Вывод которых вы явно отключили, а зря.

Там где вам нужно приводите тип явно, так упростите себе жизнь

Comment: Ура! Нужно было указать (string) в цикле, как Вы и сказали! Спасибо!

    for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++){if($i < 10){
    $arr[] = '00000' . **(string)**$i;